# Why does the Tkinter window freezes, on moving the window from the Title Bar, it starts working then

Tags: python, tkinter, db2

I have a window where I am querying a DB2 Database Table by clicking a button and it fetches the records to my window.

For few tables, after I click the Query Button, I get the records properly on my window.

But for many other tables, after I click the Query button, my window freezes. Now when I move the window by its Title Bar using the mouse button, the window quickly gets unfrozen and I get all the records from the Database Table properly.

I am displaying each records field in a `Text` widget.

Earlier when I was using `Label` widget in place of `Text` widget, I didn't get this issue.

This is something how I am creating the `Text` widget at run-time.

```
fld_name = Text(self.response_frame, background='yellow', relief=GROOVE,
                        borderwidth=1, height=1)
val_text = str(ibm_db.field_name(result, i)) # I am getting the value from DB2 database here
fld_name.configure(width=len(val_text) + 5) # As the Text widget doesn't auto-resize, so I am configuring it's size.
fld_name.insert(1.0, val_text)
fld_name['state'] = 'disabled'
fld_name.grid(column=i, row=j, sticky=(W, E))
```

Please suggest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to respect the order of changing the state of `fld_name` properly before and after insertion or deletion from **`NORMAL`** to **`DISABLED`** (or vice versa).

This means your insertion operation must look like this:

```
fld_name.configure(state='normal')
fld_name.insert(1.0, val_text)
fld_name.configure(state='disabled')
```

But still this may lead you to undesired behavior because the line fld_name.configure(state='normal') supposes your fld_name was in the opposite state (DISABLED) as I stated in the introduction paragraph above. This means you will need to perform a last modification of your code and it concerns the way you create `fld_name`:

```
fld_name = Text(self.response_frame, state = 'disabled', background='yellow', relief=GROOVE,   borderwidth=1, height=1)
```

As you can see, you need simply to add the option `state = 'disabled'` at the moment of creation in order to respect the statement of the first paragraph above.

Thus we are changing `fld_name` state in a coherent order:

**`DISABLED`** → **`NORMAL`** → **`DISABLED`**

Note that if you perform insertion or deletion of data in `fld_name` after the above line `fld_name.configure(state='disabled')` then you will need to absolutely restitute back the state of `fld_name` to **`NORMAL`**. Always respect the statement of the first paragraph of this answer.